# Private keys get deleted unexpectedly in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, private-key

I am facing a strange problem in developing an installation that should in one of the steps install a certificate.

The problem has to do with granting Certificate’s private key access for an account (e.g. IIS_IUSRS) on Windows Server 2008 R2. The private keys are stored in the location C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.

A custom C# Setup Project imports a Certificate and gives access for an account on Certificate’s private key during the installation process. After some time (2-3 sec) the private key file is automatically deleted from the MachineKeys folder. Thus the installed Web Application cannot access the specific certificate and displays the following error message:

“System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist”. This error occurs only on Windows Server 2008 R2, while for Windows Server 2003 everything is working correctly.

My question is, why the private key gets deleted and which process does this?

Thx

**UPDATE 17/05/2012**

I have not yet found a solution to the described problem, and no response has been posted on the other forums where I asked (forums.asp.net, social.msdn.microsoft.com). So, can anyone suggest any other resources or advice for further troubleshooting this issue?

Thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was happening to me too - my setup script would add the cert and grant access to the PK file fine, and the app would work.  Then later, after I had closed the PowerShell editor I re-launched the app and it failed with a keyset not found.

Adding the PersistKeySet flag when importing the cert fixed the problem.  Here's the PowerShell code for adding the cert and private key with persistence:

```
param(
    [string]$certStore = "LocalMachine\TrustedPeople",
    [string]$filename = "sp.pfx",
    [string]$password = "password",
    [string]$username = "$Env:COMPUTERNAME\WebSiteUser"
)

    function getKeyUniqueName($cert) {
         return $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
    }
    
    function getKeyFilePath($cert) {             
         return "$ENV:ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\$(getKeyUniqueName($cert))"
    }

$certFromFile = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($filename, $password)
$certFromStore = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\$certStore" | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $certFromFile.Thumbprint}
$certExistsInStore = $certFromStore.Count -gt 0
$keyExists = $certExistsInStore -and ($certFromStore.PrivateKey -ne $null) -and (getKeyUniqueName($cert) -ne $null) -and (Test-Path(getKeyFilePath($certFromStore)))

if ((!$certExistsInStore) -or (!$keyExists)) {

    $keyFlags = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::MachineKeySet 
    $keyFlags = $keyFlags -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::PersistKeySet
    $certFromFile.Import($filename, $password, $keyFlags)

    $store = Get-Item "Cert:\$certStore"
    $store.Open("ReadWrite")

    if ($certExistsInStore) {
        #Cert is in the store, but we have no persisted private key
        #Remove it so we can add the one we just imported with the key file
        $store.Remove($certFromStore)
    }

    $store.Add($certFromFile)
    $store.Close()

    $certFromStore = $certFromFile
    "Installed x509 certificate"
}

$pkFile = Get-Item(getKeyFilePath($certFromStore))
$pkAcl = $pkFile.GetAccessControl("Access")
$readPermission = $username,"Read","Allow"
$readAccessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $readPermission
$pkAcl.AddAccessRule($readAccessRule)
Set-Acl $pkFile.FullName $pkAcl
"Granted read permission on private key to web user"
```

Comment: I don't know "why?" either but we just hit this snag as well.  Same fix worked - adding PersistKeySet and MachineKeySet seemed to be the fix.  Our context was powershell script blocks from within a chef process.  The guard script worked but minus the additional parameter whacked the private key leaving the cert unusable.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: thanks! I've made a small edit to fix the $keyExists test when $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName is null and $keyExists is evaluating to true when it should be false

Answer (score 1):

Is very clear that is a security issue “**`System.Security`**.”. and you do not have permissions to do the installation., you need to set the permissions on the private key to allow that service account [access it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx).

**Edit later**: Go to Start->Run->cmd->type mmc->Select File->Add/Remove->Select Certificates->Add->Computer Account->Local., i attach a screenshot is in spanish but I indicated the fields:

[image]

Open->Certificates->Personal->Certificates->Right click Certificate-> All Tasks->Manage Private Keys->Add Network Service.

Also check this [entry](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) to see how works this feature in Windows Server 2008., then please after you try it, come back and say if you could solve the issue with what I have told you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my problem is not that the process that is supposed to read the private key (ie., group IIS_IUSRS) does not have enough access rights to do so. Rather, the problem is that the private key _is not even there_. Let me describe again the series of the events: A process (an installer of a web application) creates some private keys, appropriate files are then created in the C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys machine folder and after some seconds (before the installer process gets terminated) these files get deleted unexpectedly.

Comment: I read your updated comment. Let me clarify again the issue, because I don' t think it has been understood: The private key is created successfully with the correct access rights. The problem is that, some seconds after their successful creation, the private keys get deleted. I cannot understand what procedure deletes these private keys.

Answer (score 1):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509certificate2collection.cs,256 shows where the PersistKeySet flag is tested.  The PersistKeySet flag is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx with the phrase "The key associated with a PFX file is persisted when importing a certificate."  My techno-babble to English translator tells me this means "You must include the PersistKeySet flag if you call the X509Certificate2 constructor and the certificate might already be installed on the machine."  This probably applies to the .Import calls too.  It's likely the powershell Import-PfxCertificate cmdlet already does this.  But if you are doing what the accepted answer shows or what the OP asked, you need to include the special key.  We used a variation of ejegg's script in our solution.  We have a process that runs every 3 minutes to check that all configured certs are installed and this seems to work fine now.

The symptom we saw in powershell is the HasPrivateKey property is true but the PrivateKey value itself is null.  And the key file for the cert in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys was deleted.  The FindPrivateKey utility at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717039(v=vs.110).aspx helped us watch file get deleted.

So happy 4th birthday to the question with this very late response.